# React axios 401 unauthorized googleapis customsearch

Tags: reactjs, google-api, axios

I made an axios search with google api search but it returns 401 unauthorized (Invalid Credentials)

my code look like this

```
axios
      .get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAssMSJbk0A6Rza9aMfhjgeZiYfKH1kdn8&cx=003138940458556222423:awjyesdbipu&q=" +
          this.state.query
      )
      .then(response => this.setState({ results: response.items }));
```

Comment: Link work just fine in browser...https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAssMSJbk0A6Rza9aMfhjgeZiYfKH1kdn8&cx=003138940458556222423:awjyesdbipu&q=a

Comment: but in react it didn't get the informations

Comment: Do you get any data in the response object if you look in Dev tools network tab?

Comment: it returns : {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need an api key when you query.

Please see this link, it documents how to get a key also:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#api_key

Comment: it works fine I have the api but in react app didn't work

Comment: I believe axios uses the `data` property, try changing `response.items` to `response.data`

Comment: What does response return?

Comment: it returns {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }

Comment: Yep, you need to follow that link and sort your authentication out with google. Maybe you are using an old api!